# How to remove empty and null strings from QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qlist

I have a `QStringList` and I need to clean some meaningless elements : the empty and the null strings.

I could not find a `QStringList` shortcut function for that.
What is the simplest way to clean the empty/null strings ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myQStringList.removeAll(QString("")); // Returns the number of entries removed
```

Empty string `QString("")` and null string `QString()` both return `true` when compared to an empty string.
Then the test of [`QList::removeAll(const T &value)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#removeAll) will remove both empty and null strings from the list.

Answer (score 6):

The default-constructed `QString` compares equal to empty and null strings, thus:

```
inline void removeEmptyAndNull(QStringList &l) {
  l.removeAll({});
}
```